# SQL query that will return duplicate lottery numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been banging my head trying to write a SQL query which will return duplicate winning lottery numbers.

I have a SQL table named WinningLotteryNumbers, and a column named WinningNumbers with a data type of `vchar(14)`.  I have the WinningNumber stored in this format: `01-02-03-04-05`.

My problem is this, say I have a WinningNumber of `02-04-06-08-10` stored in the column.  Those 5 numbers are lucky and are drawn again a couple days later, but in a different order i.e `06-02-10-08-04`.  How do I query the column and get a return of all the WinningNumbers that are the same but in a different order.

I hope my question came out as clear as it did in my own head.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How are you identifying which `WinningNumber` you want to search for if you have a whole column of them?

Comment: Each WinningNumber has a WinningNumberId

Comment: Does order mean they're different? IOW, is `01-02-03-04-05` the same thing as '05-04-03-02-01' as far as both being a "winner"? If so, just make sure you sort the numbers before you store them in the first place. If not, then you don't need to count them both because they're not the same numbers.

Comment: Yes, 01-02-03-04-05 is the same as 05-04-03-02-01.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pain.  Let me suggest this approach:

```
select newWLN, count(*) as cnt
from (select LotteryNumber, group_concat(numpart order by numpart separator '-') as NewWLN
      from (select wln.LotteryNumber,
                   substring_index(substring_index(wln.LotteryNumber, '-', n.n), '-', -1) as numpart
            from WinningLotteryNumbers wln cross join
                 (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
                 ) n
           ) wln
      group by LotteryNumber
     ) nwln
group by newWLN
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc;
```

This is a brute force approach.  It splits the lottery number into the five component for each lottery number.  Then it recombines them, in order.  The final step is just aggregation to count the duplicates.

Comment: Wow.  You nailed it the head for me.  Thank you for thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

THis is only an idea. You can split all the numbers, sort them ascending, then, store again in a variable.

Then, 02-04-06-08-10 will be the same that 06-02-10-08-04 once you sort the numbers.

I hope this helps